# Law of large numbers. What is wrong here?

Tags: probability-theory, independence, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose that we have a sequence of random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots$. 
Suppose that $Q$ and $P$ are probability measures such that this sequence is i.i.d. with respect to both probability measures. 
Denote by $\mu_P$ and $\mu_Q$ the mean of $X_1$ with respect to $P$ and $Q$, respectively.

On one hand, the law of large numbers tells me that

$$ 
\lim_n \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=\mu_P\quad P-\text{ a.s.}
$$
$$ 
\lim_n \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=\mu_Q\quad Q-\text{ a.s.}
$$
On the other hand, suppose now that $Q<<P$, i.e. $P(A)=0$ implies that $Q(A)=0$.

Then, the first equality means that there exists $A$ with $P(A)=1$ such that $\lim_n \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i(\omega)=\mu_P$ for all $\omega\in A$.

Since $Q<<P$, then $Q(A)=1$. Then we derive that
$$ 
\lim_n \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=\mu_P\quad Q-\text{ a.s.}
$$

Consequently, $\mu_P=\mu_Q$. But this must be wrong, given that I can think of examples where $\mu_P$ and $\mu_Q$ are not necessarily equal.

Comment: Do you have a concrete example to what you described? Don't forget $P$ and $Q$ are different probability measures, so maybe the fact that $P(A)=Q(B)=1$ doesn't imply that $A\cap B$ is empty.

Comment: @Mark Suppose that $X_n(r_1,r_2,\ldots):=r_n$ and that $X_n$ has independent Gausian distributions with repesct $P$ and $Q$ but with different mean $\mu_P$ and $\mu_Q$, respectively. Actually $P$ and $Q$ are equivalent probability measures.

Comment: Your reasoning seems to be correct. What are the examples you are thinking of? I suspect that maybe this is the actual source of the confusion.

Comment: Be careful with the spaces $P$ and $Q$ are defined on. In your example $P$ and $Q$ are defined on $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$. They are product measures where the marginals are gaussian, but they are not equivalent. Due to the LLN such product measures put their whole mass on the set $\{ x\in  \Bbb R^{\Bbb N} : \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \mu_P\}$. I think that there is nothing wrong here.

Comment: @Falrach Thanks, this was exactly what I was thinking. Why are not the products equivalent?

Comment: Because the marginals have not the same mean.

Comment: Why do different means in the marginals imply that the products are not equivalent? Maybe you can write an answer

Comment: I was thinking the same thing and while you were discussing here, I asked this very related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3281967/is-equivalence-of-probability-measures-preserved-under-infinite-products

Comment: I don't feel like I should write an answer. The answer is contained in your post itself. Assume $\mu_P \neq \mu_Q$. Then the sets which I wrote down above on which the product measures have their whole mass are disjoint. If without loss of generality $Q << P$ we get a contradiction.

Comment: @Falrach Conclusion: My reasoning is right, so there is not counterexamples. As a corollary, if the marginals have different mean, then the products are not equivalent.

Comment: This example generalises a lot if you know some Gaussian measure theory. In your example in the comments, your $P$ is a Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ which is a product of standard Gaussians on $\mathbb{R}$. $Q$ is its pushforward by the translation in the direction $(1,1,1,\dots)$. It is known that such a pushforward is quasi-invariant with respect to the original measure if and only if the direction of translation lies in $\ell^2$ - otherwise they are mutually singular. This is a special case of a result about translations and the "Cameron-Martin space" of a Gaussian measure.