# Is equivalence of probability measures preserved under infinite products?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification, probability-distributions, product-space

For all $n\in \Bbb N$, let $\mu_n$ and $\nu_n$ be equivalent probability measures on a measurable space $(\Omega_n,\mathcal{F}_n)$. Are

$$ \mu:=\bigotimes_{n=1}^\infty\mu_n \quad \text{and} \quad \nu:=\bigotimes_{n=1}^\infty\nu_n$$

also equivalent? I highly suspect that they aren't in general, unless the following example (inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3281953/law-of-large-numbers-what-is-wrong-here)) contains a mistake. But **I'd be interested in simpler examples**, if there are any.

---

For all $n\in \Bbb N$, let $(\Omega_n,\mathcal{F}_n)=(\Bbb R,\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R))$ and $\mu_n=\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $\nu_n=\mathcal{N}(1,1)$. Let

$$ X\colon \Bbb R^\Bbb N \to \Bbb R^\Bbb N, \quad \omega=(\omega_1,\omega_2,\ldots) \mapsto \omega $$

denote the canonical variable. Its components $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ are then i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ random variables under $\mu$, and they are i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(1,1)$ random variables under $\nu$. By the Law of Large Numbers,

$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\xrightarrow[\mu-a.s.]{n\to\infty} 0, \quad \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\xrightarrow[\nu-a.s.]{n\to\infty} 1,$$

so $\mu$ and $\nu$ being equivalent would yield $0=1$.

Comment: Your example is correct. $\nu$ is the translation of $\mu$ by $(1, 1, 1, \dots)$ but it is known that a translation of $\mu$ is quasi-invariant with respect to $\mu$ if and only if it is translation by an element of $\ell^2$ - otherwise the measures are mutually singular. This is part of a general phenomenon for Gaussian measures on topological vectors spaces - the key word to search for is the "Cameron-Martin space" of the measure.

Comment: I think I found something valuable for this topic:
[Kakutanis Theorem ][1]

Here it is stated for $\Bbb R$ but in his paper I found on JStor it is stated for arbitrary measurable spaces with a Borel field.

  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakutani%27s_theorem_(measure_theory)

Comment: Thanks a lot, those are both very interesting comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, there is a complete solution to this problem provided that each $\mathcal{F}_n$ is the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra with respect to some topology on $\Omega_n$. In this case, **Kakutani's Theorem** yields the following:

> 1.) $\mu$ and $\nu$ are either equivalent or mutually singular.
>
> 2.) Set
>   $$ \rho_n:=\int_{\Omega_n} \sqrt{ \frac{\mathrm{d} \mu_n} {\mathrm{d} \nu_n} }  \mathrm{d} \nu_n.$$
>   Then $\mu$ and $\nu$ are equivalent if and only if
>   $$ \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \rho_n  >0,$$
>   which is equivalent to convergence of the series
>   $$ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \log \rho_n.$$

A proof can be found [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969123).